# Linux: retrieve per-interface sent/received packet counters (ethernet, ipv4, ipv6)

Tags: linux, networking, ip

On Linux, how can I (programmatically) retrieve the following counters *on a per-interface basis*:

- Sent/received ethernet frames,
- Sent/received IPv4 packets,
- Sent/received IPv6 packets.

Comment: It's probably somewhere in /proc, but as a quick-and-dirty you could probably parse it out of the output of "ifconfig"

Comment: Paul, that would work only for the frame count as ifconfig doesn't give a packet count per IP protocol.

Comment: xahtep hit the nail on the head: it is easy the find the frame count. I'm looking for IPv4 and IPv6 packet counts as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do this using `iptables` rules and packet counters, e.g.

```
# input and output must be accounted for separately
# ipv4, eth0
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0
iptables -I OUTPUT -o eth0
# ipv6, eth0
ip6tables -I INPUT -i eth0
ip6tables -I OUTPUT -o eth0
```

And to view the stats, parse the output of these:

```
iptables -L -vxn
ip6tables -L -vxn
```

You should also look up the `-Z` flag for when you want to reset the counters.

Comment: Sounds promising. Can you elaborate and/or point to a book/website describing this? Also, would there be a performance implication if I want this turned on "all the time" on a production system?

Comment: I updated the answer to have an example, hope this helps. There won't be any noticeable performance hit for this as it just updates a few in-memory counters as the packets flow through.

Answer (score 22):

On my system, there are files under `/sys/class/net/eth0/statistics`, which gives various stats about network interfaces.

This is assuming a vaguely recent Linux which has `/sys` (sysfs) mounted.

Comment: Fedora 14: it seems to be cool idea, for writing applications to represent RX /TX. $ php `cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_packets`

Comment: these files seem to contain ethernet frame counters, not IP related ones ?! (I get the impression that this is actually the same information as contained in `/proc/net/dev` or in the output of `ifconfig` except that it's in a convenient 'one counter per file' form.

Answer (score 12):

```
cat /proc/net/dev
```

Should contain counters, statistics, and information.

Answer (score 3):

You can always parse the various kernel status files yourself, I think this is what tools like `netstat` do.

The man page suggests:

- `/proc/net/raw` -- RAW socket information
- `/proc/net/tcp` -- TCP socket information
- `/proc/net/udp` -- UDP socket information

I guess there should be a non-proc way to do this, perhaps in `/sys` too? I had a quick look but didn't find anything.

Comment: The only relevant kernel status file which I could find was /proc/dev/net. It reports RX-OK and TX-OK per interface. I suspect these are ethernet frame counters. How would I get IPv4 and IPv6 packet counters?

Note that I'm looking for itnerface stats, not for connection (socket) stats.

Answer (score 2):

Either just parse the output of `netstat -i`. Or `strace netstat -i`, and use that to work out where it looks for the information.

Comment: netstat reports RX-OK and TX-OK per interface. I suspect these are ethernet frame counters. How would I get IPv4 and IPv6 packet counters?

Answer (score 2):

`ifconfig` tells you the amount of data transferred (bytes and packets).

Comment: ifconfig reports RX packets and TX packet per interface. I suspect these are ethernet frame counters. How would I get IPv4 and IPv6 packet counters?

Comment: No idea :/ I don't have an IPv6 system so I can't tell what ifconfig prints there :(

Answer (score 1):

The following commands give ipv4/ ipv6 stats maintained system-wide:

```
netstat --statistics

nstat -z

cat /proc/net/dev_snmp6/eth0  gives ipv6 stats per interface
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print full ethernet statistics with **ethtool**:
`ethtool -S eth1`

Answer (score 0):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (used to be Ethereal) can help you with that.

[Netstat](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) Would be my second guess

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a way to retrieve these counters on a "standard" linux system without installing any additional software.

Comment: Netstat should come pre-installed in most *nixes

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do that in C# in monodevelop:

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

foreach (NetworkInterface ni in interfaces)
{
  // perform your calculations
}
```